# Using runBlocking in Kotlin Coroutines when targeting JavaScript?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-js

Is there a way to write the Kotlin code below so that it compiles and works the same way on the JVM and in JavaScript?

```
fun <A: Any> request(request: Any): A  = runBlocking {
    suspendCoroutine<A> { cont ->
        val subscriber = { response: A ->
                cont.resume(response)
        }
        sendAsync(request, subscriber)
    }
}


fun <Q : Any, A : Any> sendAsync(request: Q, handler: (A) -> Unit) {

    // request is sent to a remote service,
    // when the result is available it is passed to handler(... /* result */)

}
```

The code compiles and works fine when compiled to target the JVM. 
A compilation error is emitted when targeting JavaScript due to non-existent function runBlocking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main problem is that you aren't asking for the thing you actually need. The code you wrote starts a coroutine, suspends it, then blocks until it's done. This is exactly equivalent to having no coroutines at all and just making a blocking network request, which is something you can't possibly expect JavaScript to allow you.

What you actually have to do is step back to the call site of `request()` and wrap it in a `launch`:

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
    val result: A = request(...)
    // work with the result
}
```

With this in place you can rewrite your request function to

```
suspend fun <A: Any> request(request: Any): A = suspendCancellableCoroutine {
    sendAsync(request, it::resume)
}
```

Comment: I don't think GlobalScope::launch is part of the Kotlin js coroutine library - this code won't compile if the target is JS

Comment: Also, I'm trying to avoid adding "suspend" to the "request" method's signature because that mean the call site has to be wrapped in a coroutine

Comment: `GlobalScope` is in `kotlinx.coroutines.experimental` so it must be available on any platform, however I don't know if it's the best option on JS. You can't avoid `suspend` and launching coroutines because that's the essence of how this works.

Comment: Ah, one important note: my code is written against version `0.26` of `kotlinx-coroutines-experimental`, recently released. It deprecates several key mechanisms like the global `launch` without a receiver.